# Binding NHibernate Proxy Objects to a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, datagridview, fluent-nhibernate

I am attempting to bind objects pulled from an NHibernate session to a DataGridView and am having problems.

I have a single session in which I fetch all of my "look-up" items that are bound to a combobox column, and then I query for the objects themselves. Somehow, this still results in proxy child objects on the main objects. I have even changed the mapping of the look-up items to eager fetch, but I still get proxies somehow.

Here is how I am fetching the objects:

```
Dim _makes As IList(Of Make) = session.QueryOver(Of Make).List
Dim _models As IList(Of Model) = session.QueryOver(Of Model).List
Dim _cars as IList(of Car) = session.QueryOver(of Car).List
' A car has a .Make and a .Model that are picked from a DGV ComboBox Column
```

The session does not query the database for the make or model of a car as I go through them because it sees it already has it in its cache. If this is the case though - why is it a proxy object anyway?

Since I cannot seem to avoid the proxies, I am wondering what the best way to bind these objects to a DataGridView is.

I've seen a few posts discussing this matter, e.g.: [NHibernate proxy causing problems with databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920227/nhibernate-proxy-causing-problems-with-databinding) but it is a few years old, and NHibernate has changed a lot since then. Are there any new or better solutions to this problem now?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I posted another question after having gotten some insight from this post. I have also found a simple solution to the problem - you can see it here: [Binding a collection of objects to a ComboboxColumn in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981648/binding-a-collection-of-objects-to-a-comboboxcolumn-in-a-datagridview/8997797#8997797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NHibernate is doing what you asked. 
In your mapping file, you're telling the NH to not bring the associations. Even if you bring all the associated classes, NH still has it's orders.

If you want NHibernate eager load the Make and Model class from your Car, you have two ways to do it:

1. If you only need these objects from time to time, **Change your Query**;
2. If you always need these objects when dealing with the Car class, **Change your mapping**;

The first one is easy. You just need to do a JoinAlias and the NH will bring the objects to you like this:

```
Car carAlias = null;
Model modelAlias = null;
Make makeAlias = null;

var query = Session.QueryOver<Car>(()=> carAlias)
            .JoinAlias(()=> carAlias.Model, ()=> modelAlias)
            .JoinAlias(()=> carAlias.Make, ()=> makeAlias)
           .Where(()=> carAlias.Id == 101).SingleOrDefault();
```

This query will bring this one time the Car and the two associated classes (Model and Make).

The second one is easier that the first, but be careful, it could lead you into troubles with N+1 selects.

Go to you mapping where you set the  to the Model and Make and change the lazy="false".

Now, every time you fetch a Car object the Model and Make will be together.  This solutions affects other queries that rely on mapping files.

I Hope it helps you!

Comment: This makes sense, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. I've stepped through the code and watched this get executed, and I also tried simply doing a .Fetch(). It still results in proxy objects, even though the query goes and requests the full data from the database again (even though it is still in the cache). Any other ideas?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was misunderstanding parts of NHibernate as well as not fully understanding some blog posts I read. The issue I am having seems to be more data-binding centric. Once I deal with that red herring I will take another look at the NHibernate side of it.

Comment: Just my 2 cents again :)
I don't recommend you to use your NHibernate mapped entities directly in your GUI components (Datagrids, DropDown and etc...). 
It may lead you to problems like selects N+1 (again) or even worse scenario: You can get exceptions if your ISession object is closed during runtime.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of these issues and have taken measures to remove them. None of the data is lazily loaded into the GUI, and the ISession stays alive for the life of the GUI.