# Binding a collection of objects to a ComboboxColumn in a DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a GUI which allows the user to select a report to view/edit. When the user selects a report, it shows the Items in the report. The Item has many properties - most of which are binding properly. One of the properties is Owner, and this is bound to a ComboBoxColumn.

- Report

  - Items

    - Owner

I have done something very similar to this a few times and had no problems when I set the `DataPropertyName`, `DataSource`, `ValueMember`, and `DisplayMember`. The only difference is that this time instead of the `Item` type having an `OwnderID` it actually has an instance of the `Owner` object.

I saw a suggestion on another post to solve this issue by giving the items bound in the list a self-referencing property that allows them to return themselves for the purposes of setting the `ValueMember`

However, When I bind it this way:

```
OwnerColumn.DataPropertyName = "Owner"
OwnerColumn.DataSource = ownersBindingSource1
OwnerColumn.ValueMember = "Self"
OwnerColumn.DisplayMember = "OwnerName"
```

I get a lot of errors like:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Owner'.
```

and:

```
The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:

System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.
```

I was able to get around some of these errors by binding it like this:

```
OwnerColumn.DataPropertyName = "Owner"
OwnerColumn.DataSource = ownersBindingSource1
```

and also by making the `ToString` function on the `Owner` display the `OwnerName` property. This seems pretty hacky though - and I think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental as it still does not function properly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that a lot of my errors were coming from my misunderstanding of various articles I had read, as well as sloppy code.

I neglected to specify the return type on a few of the properties, option explicit / option strict were both off, and there had been some corruption in my designer and a few of the columns were duplicated.

A solution to this that I liked the most was: http://code.google.com/p/systembusinessobjects/source/browse/trunk/System.BusinessObjects.Framework/Data/SafeBindingLists.cs . Unfortunately, this requires Castle proxy, and an older version of NHibernate.

***Here is the simple solution that I found:***

The issue is that you cannot bind a list with objects of multiple types. The goal is to be able to have the ComboBox directly set the value of a property on the object it is bound to with another object.

I chose to use a View object, and bind the list to that.

View Object:

```
Public Class OwnerView
    Private _owner As Owner

    Public ReadOnly Property OwnerId As Integer
        Get
            Return _owner.OwnerId
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property OwnerName As String
        Get
            Return _owner.OwnerName
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property OwnerAbbreviation As String
        Get
            Return _owner.OwnerAbbreviation
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Self As Owner
        Get
            Return _owner
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal owner As Owner)
        _owner = owner
    End Sub

End Class
```

Binding:

```
With OwnerColumn
    .SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
    .ReadOnly = False
    .Name = "OwnerColumn"
    .HeaderText = "Owner"

    Dim bs As New BindingSource()

    For Each co As Owner In Owners
        bs.Add(New OwnerView(co))
    Next

    .DataPropertyName = "Owner"
    .DataSource = bs
    .ValueMember = "Self"
    .DisplayMember = "OwnerName"

    ItemDataGridView.Columns.Add(OwnerColumn)
End With
```